# Move commit made in detached HEAD back to branch, but not on top

Tags: git

1. I was on `current` branch and did commit `good`.
2. Then I commited `irrelevant`.
3. I went back, checked out `good` (detached HEAD now).
4. I did commit `one`, in detached HEAD state.

I would like to have some help to put `one` just after `good`, in `current` branch.

It doesn't matter if I lost `irrelevant`.

Comment: Regarding your edit, commits aren't "on" or "in" branches.  Git calls all the various ways to refer to commits "references", and "a branch" in git is just "a branch tip reference", a label for a currently-particular commit.  You can rehang the label anywhere you like, at any time.  When you do a `git commit`, git rehangs the `HEAD` reference, and that's it.  Really.  A huge portion of the confusion around git derives from people's preconceived notion that this has to be hard or complicated.  It's not.  It's simple.  What you can _do_ with it gets complicated, but that's the job, not the tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3. I went back, checked out `good` (detached `HEAD` now).
> 4. I did commit `one`, in detached `HEAD` state.
>
> I would like to have some help to put one just after good.

`one` *is* after `good`.  `git commit` updates `HEAD`, every time, no matter what.  When you check out a branch tip, git sets the `HEAD` reference as an alias for that branch tip reference, it "attaches" it to that branch tip reference.  A detached `HEAD` is just a reference directly to a particular commit, so when `git commit` updates it, `HEAD` now refers to the new one.  But `git commit` *always* adds the old `HEAD` commit as the parent of the new one.

So just

```
git checkout -B current one               # if you don't still have `one` checked out
```

or just

```
git checkout -B current                   # if you do
```

Comment: This is the right (upvoted :-) ) answer, and the easiest way to deal with the situation. I will add one nuance (which I'm sure jthill knows and it's mostly irrelevant, so a comment makes a good footnote): the *always* here gets modified slightly when you use `git commit --amend`. The `--amend` option tells `git commit` to use, not the current (HEAD) commit, but rather the current commit's parent(s). That's how Git fakes the amending (which isn't actually changing *anything*, but instead is adding a new commit, as usual—well, *almost* as usual).